# Does converse of Lagrange's theorem hold for a group of order 21?

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group of order $n=21$. Now is it possible for converse of Lagrange's theorem to hold? Or if $m \mid n$ will there certainly be a subgroup of order $m$ and if yes are the subgroup unique?

Comment: Think about Sylow subgroups. That shuold  give the answer.

Comment: If n = 21= 3×7. Then by Sylow's theory of p groups,  subgroups of order 3 and 7 exists. But will the subgroups be unique? @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг

Comment: Have you read the second and third parts of Sylow's theorem? They will be of help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question of @shadow kh refers to the class of finite groups known as *CLT groups*, where CLT stands for *Converse Lagrange Theorem*:

$G$ is a *CLT group* if for each positive integer $d$ dividing $|G|$, $G$ has at least one subgroup of order $d$.

These groups have been studied extensively. It turns out for example that all [supersolvable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersolvable_group) groups are CLT, and all CLT groups are [solvable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group). See also one of the early [papers](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102983900) of Henry G. Bray, Pac. J. Math 27 (1968). All $p$-groups, or in general nilpotent groups, are supersolvable.
For groups of order $21$ you do not necessarily need Sylow theory, the Theorem of Cauchy suffices: there are elements of order $3$ and $7$ hence subgroups of that order.

Answer (score 0):

It does not hold in general that if $|G|=n$ and $m|n$ that there is a subgroup of $G$ of order $m$. For example [$A_5$ has order $60$ and no subgroup of order $20$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Alternating_group:A5).

It may interest you however to look [Hall's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_subgroup#Hall.27s_theorem) or [Sylow's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems) which prove existence of subgroup of order $m$ for some values of $m|n$. As mentioned in comments, for $n=21$ Sylow's Theorem gives the result you're looking for.